# Javascript not affecting content that is loaded by another script

Tags: php, javascript

I am using jQuery to load a php form and bootstrap.js for a datepicker element on that form; this code is in a file script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // load form via ajax when button is clicked is submitted
    $('.add-opportunity .open').on('click', function() {

        // get form
        $('.add-opportunity').load('add_opportunity.php'); 
    });

    // datepicker
$('#datepicker').datepicker();        
});
```

With this format the datepicker does not function. If however, I put the jQuery in the php file, also in document(ready), it functions properly. I would like to keep all my javascript in separate files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings are made before your form is loaded. Instead you should bind the datepicker once your form is loaded in your callback of onload event.

```
$('.add-opportunity').load('add_opportunity.php', function(){
    // datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();  
});
```